# Clipping a raster with several polygon features - saving output rasters according to a field name in the polygon layer

Tags: arcpy, raster, clip

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1. and I'm a beginner with Python. I'm trying to clip a raster layer with a polygon layer (shapefile) that has multiple features. The tool should

1. clip the raster according to those multiple polygon features, and then
2. name the new output rasters according to a field name (FID) in the polygon layer.

   - Example input raster name: RasterFile.tif
   - Example output raster name: RasterFile_FID0.tif (this would be the first raster)

I have a code (from @Midavalo) that I have used to do the first part (code below). This works just fine, but I can't figure it out how to modify the code so that it would do the second part.

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:\Folder\Subfolder"
outputWorkspace = r"E:\Folder\Subfolder\Outputs"
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()
clipShapefile = r"Grid.shp"
clipShapes = set()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(clipShapefile, ['OID@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        clipShapes.add(row[0])

for raster in rasterlist:
    rastername, rasterext = os.path.splitext(raster)
    for i in clipShapes:
        newRaster = "{}_clip_{}.img".format(rastername, i)
        newRasterPath = os.path.join(outputWorkspace, newRaster)
        if arcpy.Exists('clipLayer'):
            arcpy.Delete_management('clipLayer')
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(clipShapefile, 'clipLayer', ' "FID" = {}'.format(i)) 
        arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "#", newRasterPath, 'clipLayer', "0", "ClippingGeometry") 
        arcpy.Delete_management('clipLayer')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line sets your new filename.

```
newRaster = "{}_clip_{}.img".format(rastername, i)
```

The output will look something like `RasterFilename_clip_1.img` where `RasterFilename` is the name of your raster, and `1` is the FID.

You just need to change this line to your new filename structure.  Since you want something like `RasterFilename_FID1.tif`, you just need to remove `_clip` and add `FID` (and change the raster output extension).  Something like this should produce what you want:

```
newRaster = "{}_FID{}.tif".format(rastername, i)
```

Comment: Of course, so simple! I will try it out with my data and when I confirm it works I'll tag your answer as the right one. Thank you!

Comment: I ran the code with the suggested changes and it's giving me an error (ERROR 999998) relating to the MakeFeatureLayer, line 18: arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(clipShapefile, 'clipLayer', ' "FID" = {}'.format(i)). What did I miss?

Comment: @FiveO Does it tell you any more in the error message?

Comment: I rebooted everything and now it works. Thank you!